# Display Pie Chart Percentages in R studio from Dataset

Tags: r, dataset, pie-chart, data-analysis, percentage

I'm trying to display the percentages of distinct value occurrences for each column in my dataset using R.

This simple line of code creates a table from the specified column and displays a perfect pie chart with the correct distributions. However, I can't seem to display the percentage values.

I believe there is a short and simple way to do this.

This is what i have so far. Please what do i need to add?

```
> workclass <- table(adult$workclass)
> pie(workclass)
```

Thanks.

These are the values in my "workclass" column that i have a pie chart for. I just need to display their percentage distributions on the pie chart.

```
Federal-gov - 1836 Occurrences     
Local-gov - 960 Occurrences
Never-worked - 2093 Occurrences
Private - 120 Occurrences
Self-emp-inc - 2541 Occurrences
Self-emp-not-inc - 1116 Occurrences
State-gov - 2093 Occurrences
Without-pay - 1298 Occurrences
```

Comment: `pie(workclass/sum(workclass)) `

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it didn't make any difference. The pie chart still displays no percentage values.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that your problem was the labels.   Try`pie(workclass, labels=workclass/sum(workclass))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this code works for you, to display the percentages in the pie chart.

```
adult <- data.frame(workclass = c(rep("Federal-gov",1836),rep("Local-gov",960),rep("Never-worked",2093),
                                  rep("Private",120), rep("Self-emp-inc",2541), rep("Self-emp-not-inc",1116),
                                  rep("State-gov",2093),rep("Without-pay",1298))) 
           Occurrences = c(1836,960,2093,120,2541,1116,2093,1298))

workclass <- table(adult$workclass)


par(mar = c(2,2,2,2))
lb = paste0(round(prop.table(workclass)*100,2),"%")
pie(workclass,labels = lb, col = rainbow(8))
legend(-2.1,0.4,legend=names(workclass),cex=0.7,yjust=0.2, xjust = -0.1,
       fill = rainbow(8), bty = "n")
```

[image]

```
prop.table(workclass)
Federal-gov        Local-gov     Never-worked          Private     Self-emp-inc Self-emp-not-inc 
     0.152276686      0.079621796      0.173592104      0.009952725      0.210748943      0.092560338 
       State-gov      Without-pay 
     0.173592104      0.107655304
```